# Formatting of images for publication with Matlab

Tags: publications, graphics

I'm currently working on my first publication and heard from a colleague that the images must have precisely the same font size as the article's font. She told me that Origin could adjust this. Unfortunately, she works with Origin and I with Matlab, so that she cannot tell me how I can set this up with Matlab. Can someone give me a tip or an excellent workflow to create pictures that can be published with Matlab?

Comment: I would be rather surprised if a journal actually expects you to submit with *exactly* the same font size in figures as in text. Figures often get resized in production, and so a perfect correspondence would be hard to achieve. Rather, the journals that I am familiar with say that fonts should be *at least* as big as the font used in the caption - which can be easily assessed 'by eye'.

Comment: Hello Andrea! Are you looking for a TeX-based solution? In this case, you might be interested in looking at the corresponding SE at tex.stackexchange.com, where approximate solutions already exist AFAIK.

Comment: @avid I would expect the same. Does your comment suffice for a full answer?

Comment: @JonasSchwarz My supervisor asked me to write it in word. In the author guidelines, I just found a description for the size of the figures and the dpi.

Comment: @avid I have not published an article before so I just heard this fact. I was wondering as well and have not found anything about this in the author's guidelines.

Comment: Just do  what the authors' guidelines tell you. Too bad you have to use word (what does the journal want? pdf?)

Comment: @EthanBolker Ok, in the authors' guidelines they don't specify something about it. Just the picture size. The journal takes pdf and tex files as well. But the supervisor wants to review it in word so he can change something quickly.